# View not updating in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing infinite-scrolling in AngularJs. The below function gets called on a successful AJAX call, that takes place when:

1. The user scrolls to the end of screen.
2. The selects some filters, and hits the "Search" button.

In the first case, the data fetched from the AJAX call is appended to the existing list. In the second case, I intend to completely empty any existing data in the list, and display the new data. Here is my code to do that:

```
$scope.successCallBack=function(data){
$('#spn-model-buffering-image').hide();   //hide the loading spinner icon
if($scope.providersList === null) {
   $scope.providersList = []; /* init if null */
}
if($scope.scrolled === 'true'){
/*If it was an scroll-end event, then simply append the new data to the existing one*/
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.providersList, JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist));   //push the new data to the existing list
}
else{
/*If the user clicks on "Search Providers" button, then new data are fetched, and occupy the entire list view*/
$scope.providersList=[];
$scope.providersList=JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist);
}
viewToBeDisplayed(LIST_VIEW);
$scope.scrolled='true';
```

}

So, after a successful AJAX call, the above method is called. It hides the buffering image, and checks if the variable named scrolled is set to true. If yes, then it means that the event is not button-click, but the user has reached the end of screen, and hence, data have to be appended. Else, the user has clicked on the button, and hence, data have to be displayed fresh.

This is the function that gets called on button-click event:

```
$scope.getFilteredData=function(){
 $scope.scrolled='false';
 $scope.getMoreData();
}
```

My problem: View does not get updated. The AJAX call returns data as JSON. In the scroll-event, data are fetched and appended to the existing list, as expected.
Can someone suggest me what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Here is the AJAX call code:

```
$scope.getMoreData=function(){
  $('#spn-model-buffering-image1').show();   //while the data are being fetched, display the loading spinner
  $scope.updateAjaxData();   //update AJAX data: pagekey, category, and reftag
  var url=$scope.getURL();
  A.ajax(url, {
      method: 'post',
      params: AJAX_DATA,
      success: function(data, s, x) {
          $scope.successCallBack(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown) {
          $scope.errorCallback(xhr);
      }
 });
}
```

Comment: Try use `http` service instead `ajax` call. or use `scope.$applay()` after `$scope.successCallBack(data);` It is not good at all using jquery code in angular.

Comment: Using scope.$apply() does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the http provided by AngularJS.

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

This is good practice and it will probably solve your problem of not updating the view.